# Writing matrix multiplication in summation notation

Tags: matrices, notation, index-notation

I have a $1$-D matrix $V_x$ of length $N\times 1$ (here $x$ represent that the elements of $V$ depend upon variable $x$). And a 2D matrix $T$ of dimension $N\times N$. The elements of both matrices are quantum operators, so there order matters. Both matrices are connected via a relations
$$
V_x^\dagger = \left(TV_{-x}\right)^T \tag{1}
$$
and
$$
V_{x} = T\left(V_{-x}^\dagger\right)^T \tag{2}
$$
here $\dagger$ represents the conjugate transpose of the matrix.

I want to write Eq $(1)$ and $(2)$ in summation notation, something like $\left(V_x^\dagger\right)_i=\left(\sum_j {T_{ij}\left(V_{-x}\right)_j}\right)^T$.

The main confusion that I am having is about the Transpose operators. I am unsure which element should come first when written in the summation notations.

Sorry for such a messed-up question.

Answer (score 0):

You could write something like
\begin{align*} V_x^\dagger &= (TV_{-x})^T \\
\implies\left[V_x^\dagger\right]_{1i} &= T_{ij} \left[V_{-x}\right]_{j1},
\end{align*}
to clarify that the $i$-th column in $V_x^\dagger$ (which is a row vector) is the $i$-th row in $TV_{-x}$ (which is a column vector).